# MAGENTO 2: How to update meta tag for category page when filter selected?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I want to change the Meta Tag to NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW I am trying with setting an observer, but m having very hard time to find exact event.

My events.xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="pinkblue_seo" instance="PinkBlue\SeoUrl\Observer\ChangeMetaTags" />
    </event>

</config>
```

The observer file is :

```
<?php

namespace PinkBlue\SeoUrl\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ChangeMetaTags implements ObserverInterface {


    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){
         rm_state()->controllerSet($observer['controller_action']);

        if($observer->getEvent()->getAction()->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_category_view'){
            $uri = $observer->getEvent()->getAction()->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
            if(stristr($uri,"?"))// looking for a ?
            {
                $layout       = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
                $product_info = $layout->getBlock('head');
                $layout->getUpdate()->addUpdate('<reference name="head"><action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</value></action></reference>');
                $layout->generateXml();
            }
        }

}
```

**Answer : when we want to do it only for category filter is applied. It worked **

```
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $full_action_name = $observer->getFullActionName();

        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
        if($full_action_name == 'catalog_category_view'){
            $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

            if(stristr($uri,"?"))
            {
                $this->_pageConfig->setRobots('NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW');
            }
            //print_r($layout->getBlock('head')->getRobots());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your observer is not right,

You need need to use `layout_generate_blocks_before` event.

Then using

> ```
> $this->_pageConfig->setRobots('NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW');
> ```

Here `$this->_pageConfig` is  `\Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config`

**Observer** file *`ObserverChangeMetaTagForCategory.php`* is located  `app/code/Devamitbera/ChangeMetaTags/Observer/`

```
<?php
namespace Devamitbera\ChangeMetaTags\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class ObserverChangeMetaTagForCategory implements ObserverInterface
{


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag
     */
    protected $_actionFlag;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
     */
    protected $redirect;


    private $_pageConfig;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $pageConfig     
    ) {
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
         $this->_pageConfig = $pageConfig; 
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
        $full_action_name = $observer->getFullActionName();

        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
        if($full_action_name == 'catalog_category_view'){
            //print_r($layout->getBlock('head')->getRobots());
            $this->_pageConfig->setRobots('NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW');
        }

    }

}
```

Full module available at [github](https://github.com/devamitbera/Magento2-extension/tree/master/Magento%202%20Change%20meta%20robot%20using%20observer/)

Comment: Hey I tried but it is changing meta tags even after selecting categories, while i want only when filer is applied

Comment: @amit Is it possible to change <meta property="og:title" content="Test"/> custom meta tag from controller?

Comment: hi amit bera, any help appreciated thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/330072/57334

Comment: Thank you....It's worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

events.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_generate_blocks_after">
        <observer name="result_robots" instance="Vendor\ResultRobots\Observer\ResultRobotsObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Observer:

```php
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config;

class ResultRobotsObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public $request;

    public $layoutFactory;

    public $layerResolver;

    public function __construct(
        Http $request,
        Config $layoutFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
        $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $fullActionName = $this->request->getFullActionName();
        $filtersCount = sizeof($this->layerResolver->get()->getState()->getFilters());

        if ($fullActionName == "catalog_category_view" &&
            $filtersCount > 1) {
            $this->layoutFactory->setRobots('NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW');
        }
    }
}
```